# Failed to load c++ bson extension with windows

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I know this has been asked many times but I still get this after installing mongoose on Windows 8. I don't even see anything bson related in this path:

```
node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules

2015-03-31  07:08 PM    <DIR>          .
2015-03-31  07:08 PM    <DIR>          ..
2015-03-31  07:08 PM    <DIR>          mongodb-core
2015-03-31  07:08 PM    <DIR>          readable-stream
```

Am I doing the installation wrong?

This is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "chatapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
"socket.io": "latest",
"body-parser": "~1.12.0",
"cookie-parser": "~1.3.4",
"debug": "~2.1.1",
"express": "~4.12.2",
"jade": "~1.9.2",
"morgan": "~1.5.1",
"serve-favicon": "~2.2.0"
}
  }
```

Comment: Can you post your `package.json` file and some more info on what is going on?

Comment: `bson` is a compilable addon. Do you have VS2010 or newer installed?